# How to print setSalary()?

Tags: java

I want to print how much my salary increase.

**Employee** class:

```
public class Employee {

    public void setSalary(double i) {
        this.salario = i;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return this.salario;
    }

    private double salary;
}
```

**TestEmployee** class:

```
public class TestEmployee {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        e1.setEmployee(100);
        System.out.println("My salary increase by " + e1.setSalary());
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `getSalary()` return? How do you do `String` concatenation? You should really read the Java Trails tutorials on Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: Maybe  you should have a second field for storing the most recent increase in the salary.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `getSalary` returns `double` of course.  What data type would you expect an amount of money to be stored in? :-)

Comment: @DavidWallace I *really* hope you're being ironic there. (ok, there's the smiley... phew...)

Comment: @MichaelT My last two clients (a major bank and a multi-national finance company) would both hope so too.

Comment: @DavidWallace unfortunately, I could tell you about some Point of Sales software *not* to buy... (third party, previous employer licensed it, we fixed bugs...)... but anyways... its an all too common error.

Comment: I just realize this is a bad example. I want to print what goes inside setSalary(). In my example would be 100. Thanks for being nice guys.

Comment: You want to print what goes inside `setSalary`. Only two places know about that. The code that puts it and the code that receives it. Print it out at any of those two places.

Comment: Are you sure you want to print how much your salary _increases_? In the above code, it looks like you are setting a value for `salary` and then you're trying to print it. In that case, in your print statement you should be calling `e1.getSalary()` instead of `e1.setSalary()`.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up. Forget the question. I want to print this: 
public void Method("this value")
System.out.println("this value");

Answer (score 0):

You should never print a setMethod();

set are void (doesn't return nothing), and they are there to change the values. Whenever printing you must call the getMethod();

That being said you are also confused with terminology and with the language as you mixed **Salary** and **salario** a few times.

**Employee:**

```
public class Employee {
    private double salary;
    public void setSalary(double i) {
        this.salary = i;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return this.salary;

    }

}
```

**TestEmployee:**

public class TestEmployee {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Employee e1 = new Employee();
    e1.setSalary(100.00);
    System.out.println("My salary was set to " + e1.getSalary());
}
```

}

Note that you have to SET the salary that is an attribute of the employee, and not the employee.

**If you want to increase the value you can do:**

```
setSalary(getSalary()+ 50.00);
```

Mixing English with your language is not a good idea when coding/posting.  Always, when you are trying to post here, make sure you translate your **entire** code.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete translation. My example is bad. I want to print what goes inside setSalary(). In my example would be 100.

Comment: No, you are not understanding it. You will use the set and pass the value, but to retrieve it you must use the getSalary(); 

**The setSalary() will never print anything.**

Comment: setSalario() es un metodo que modifica el valor del salario, pero cuando quieres mostrar esto valur en lo terminal (console) deves chamar lo metodo getSalario() que retorna el valor del salario atual.

setSalario significa poner un valor en el la propriedad salario y getSalario significa receber lo valor atual de la propriedad. Sorry for my poor Spanish.

Comment: I want to print this: public void Method("this value") System.out.println("this value");

Comment: Kyllopardiun - kudos for not using Google Translate.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
public class Employee {

    private BigDecimal salary;
    private BigDecimal latestChangeInSalary;

    public Employee(BigDecimal salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
        latestChangeInSalary = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    }

    public void setSalary(BigDecimal salary) {
        if ( ! salary.equals(this.salary)) {
            latestChangeInSalary = salary.subtract(this.salary);
        }
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public BigDecimal getLatestChangeInSalary() {
        return latestChangeInSalary;
    }
}
```